# SeaBIOS cannot be compiled for qemu on Andriod/Termux

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, qemu, termux

When I tried to compile SeaBIOS version 1.14 with a little touch of SMBIOS cpu speed modifications I got 3 errors, and a warning, here's the errors and warnings I got

clang-14: error: unknown argument: '-mpreferred-stack-boundary=2'
clang-14: error: unsupported option '-freg-struct-return' for target 'armv7a-unknown-linux-android24'
clang-14: error: the clang compiler does not support '-march=i386'
clang-14: warning: optimization flag '-fno-merge-constants' is not supported [-Wignored-optimization-argument]

make: *** [Makefile:141: out/src/misc.o] Error 1

Answer (score 0):

SeaBIOS is an x86 program, and you appear to be trying to compile it with a compiler that creates Arm binaries. You need to use an x86 compiler (possibly a cross-compiler, if you really want to compile it on an Arm host).